# Loading UIView from Bundle only fills screen partially

Tags: swift, uiview, nsbundle

[image: Screenshot from simulator iphone xr]

Hello there.

Using Swift 4, I am attempting to load a Custom UIView with XIB onto a UIViewController.

However, it only seems to fill the screen partially, and I'm not sure why.

I did the following:

1. The view controller is defined in a UIStoryboard
2. UIViewController that adds the UIView in the `viewDidLoad`
3. The UIView swift file and the XIB are connected via the File Owner property
4. The XIB file is added into the `copy bundle resources`
5. The hot pink background color is set using the Xcode visual editor, its not done in code.
6. I simulate using the iphone xr, but I get the same issue if I simulate on iPhone 6s

The view controller code is empty, but I've included the relevant part:

```
// QuestionViewController
class QuestionViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let subview = QuestionView()
        self.view.addSubview(subview)
    }
}
```

The UIView is also pretty basic:

```
class QuestionView: UIView, XibView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupXib()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupXib()
    }

    func setupXib() {
        guard let v = loadFromXib() else {
            return
        }
        addSubview(v)
    }
}
```

I use a protocol that I found on stackoverflow to load the xib file from bundle.  Originally I had a lot of issues even loading the bundle, but fortuently I was able to rectify this issue.  Anyway, my XIB protocol file is here:

```
// XIB protocol file
protocol XibView {
    func setupXib()
    func constrainView(_ view: UIView)
    func loadFromXib() -> UIView?
}

extension XibView where Self: UIView {
    func setupXib() {
        if let xibView = loadFromXib() {
            addSubview(xibView)
            constrainView(xibView)
        }
    }

    func constrainView(_ view: UIView) {
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                withVisualFormat: "V:|[view]|",
                options: [.alignAllCenterX, .alignAllCenterY],
                metrics: nil,
                views: ["view": view]
            )
        )

        addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                withVisualFormat: "H:|[view]|",
                options: [.alignAllCenterX, .alignAllCenterY],
                metrics: nil,
                views: ["view": view]
            )
        )
    }

    func loadFromXib() -> UIView? {
        let xibView = UINib(nibName: String(describing: Self.self), bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self))).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
        return xibView
    }
}
```

--

**Question:**

Why does the UIView not fill the entire screen or only fill the screen partially and how can I resolve this?

With thanks

Edit:

The storyboard looks for the UIViewController only has a single view with no content.

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a UIview(0,0,0,0 four constraints) in Your Viewcontroller and then assign it a custom  class which is a subclass of UIView and then load the Xib file and it will surely occupy the whole screen

Try this man::----

```
 class QuestionViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let subview = QuestionView()
            subview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.width)
            self.view.addSubview(subview)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried to create a UIView as a variable `var subview = QuestionView()` but this has the same effect.   I am wanting to keep the UIView seperate from the UIViewController because I am needing to do a lot of UIView animations and other associated code which do not belong in the UIViewController.

Comment: I am not sure where I'd put a UIView of (0,0,0,0) or why this would work, can you post some code to show where you'd put it?

Comment: If I add a UIView physically into the storyboard UIViewController and pin all corners to edges using constraints and also rename the class to match my custom UIView and add an outlet to the UIViewController that also matches the UIViewController then it will work -- but I don't see why I should have to do this, other examples I've seen do not add UIViews to the storyboard

Comment: Ok, I will give it a go

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked fine.  I'm not sure why I needed to set the             subview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.width) inside my viewcontroller, but I am more than happy that it works. upvoted, and accepted